# How to create a border with a specific distance from the left and right and the border should end at the html page end

Tags: html, css

I wanna create a margin for my website with the following criteria:

- I should be able to specify the distance from left (1st line) and distance from right (2nd line)
- The margin should end only at the page end and not till the end of the visible part of the page

[image]

My tries (It is very bad):

```css
  h1 {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
         }
         
         h2{
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            
         }
         body {   
            background-color: #feb236;
         }
         iframe {
            border: 2px solid black;
         }
         #leftLine
         {
             position: absolute;
             border-right: 1px solid black;
             top: 0;
             bottom: 0;
         }
         body{
             height: 175vh;
         }
         div{
            border-width: 0 2px;
            border-style: solid;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 400px;
            left: 400px;
         }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Plagiarism</title>
      <h1><u>Plagiarism</u></h1>
      <div></div>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <h2 style=>What is Plagiarism?</h2>
      <p align="center"><iframe></iframe></p>
      <h2>What is Plagiarism in Computer Science?</h2>
      <p align="center"><iframe></iframe></p>
      <h2>Famous Cases of Plagiarism</h2>
      <p align="center"><iframe></iframe></p>
      <h2>Punishment for Plagiarism in US</h2>
      <p align="center"><iframe></iframe></p>
   </body>
   
   
</html>
```

It creates a line but only till the end of visible page and I can't specify the distance from left (1st line)

Any help would be appreciated. Ty

Comment: Hey Roshan, here at stack overflow we appreciate it when users show the effort that they have gone through to solve their problem, can you do that please?

Comment: @EvanBechtol Yeah just a second. Lemme update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like this. Make a `div` element, and `position` it as `fixed`. Add `border-left` and `border-right` to it. I have used `border-width` and `border-style` for that. The `top` and `bottom` specify the gap between the element, from top and bottom. Same goes for `left` and `right` for the gap from left and right.

```css
body{
  height: 500vh;
}

div{
  border-width: 0 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This works but the iframe's scrollbar inside my webpage is frozen.

Comment: @Roshan can you provide us with a snippet where we can see the problem :)

Comment: @Roshan I have updated the code. The `div` positioned as fixed must be a direct child of `body`.